Confusion regarding small-O notation in a graph theory paper
Let $G$ be an $n$-vertex $d$-regular graph, where $d = n^{0.25}$. Choosing $s$ to be a constant, consider the quantity
\begin{equation}
((n - d)d - s)^2.
\end{equation}
Expanding this out, we can write it as
\begin{equation}
((n - d)d - s)^2 = \left(1 - \frac{2s}{(n-d) \cdot d} + \frac{s^2}{(n-d)^2 \cdot d^2} \right) \cdot d^2 (n - d)^2.
\end{equation}
Is the $\mathsf{RHS}$ equal to
\begin{equation}
((n - d)d - s)^2 = \left(1 - o(1) \right) \cdot d^2 (n - d)^2?
\end{equation}
I think so, because
\begin{equation}
\frac{2s}{(n-d) \cdot d} > \frac{s^2}{(n-d)^2 \cdot d^2},
\end{equation}
so the negative term should dominate.

However, in this paper, on page $647$, it is written that
\begin{equation}
((n - d)d - s)^2 = \left(1 \color{red}{+} o(1) \right) \cdot d^2 (n - d)^2?
\end{equation}
Is this a misuse of the small-$\mathsf{O}$ notation? And, if so, is this paper wrong? For instance, the proof of their central Theorem, that is Theorem $1.3$, seems to be sensitive to this distinction (otherwise, in the variance value calculation, the joint expectation value becomes negative.)

I don't know what this particular paper says, but many people use $o(1)$ to mean any function that goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, whether positive or negative or sometimes both. Thus $1+o(1)$ and $1-o(1)$ are interchangeable.

They are the same. $f\in o(g)$ just means $f/g\to0$
